# Jetpack Compose remember keyword

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm iOS developer using swiftui.
Now I have a android project so I start to learn jetpack compose.

but I have a question below which is different from swiftui state.

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.compose.material3.Slider import androidx.compose.material3.Text import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf import androidx.compose.runtime.remember import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview import com.example.myapplication.ui.theme.MyApplicationTheme import kotlin.random.Random import kotlin.random.nextInt

@Composable fun MainScreen() {
    var sliderValue by remember { mutableStateOf(0.5f) }
    var targetValue: Int = Random.nextInt(0..100)

    Text(text = ("The Target score is $targetValue"))
    TargetSlider(value = sliderValue, changeValue = {value ->
        sliderValue = value
    }) }

@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi = true) @Composable fun MainScreenPreview() {
    MyApplicationTheme {
        MainScreen()
    } }
```

I think because I didn't declare targetValue as remember, so When I move slider in live-preview,  targetValue in Text(text = ("The Target score is $targetValue") should not change.

but when I check in live-preview, or run app,and whenever I move slider the $targetValue in slider is changing... which I can not understand.

MY THOUGHT :
(1) variable declared as "by remember" updates UI when changed.
(2) WHEN Random.nextInt() is called? and Why targetValue is changing everytime I move slider..?

HELP

Comment: Did the answer below resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Jetpack Compose, we have the concept called **recomposition**. According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lifecycle#:%7E:text=Then%2C%20when%20the%20state%20of,Composition%20to%20reflect%20any%20changes.), a recomposition is defined as follows:

> Recomposition is when Jetpack Compose re-executes the composables that
> may have changed in response to state changes, and then updates the
> Composition to reflect any changes.

Whenever a Composable is re-executed, **all state that is not stored via `remember` is lost**. You can use `remember` so that a value persists through recompositions.

With the line

```
var targetValue: Int = Random.nextInt(0..100)
```

this variable will be recreated at every recomposition.

So whenever you drag the slider,

- the state stored in the `sliderValue` variable is updated,
- the `MainScreen` Composable recomposes to display the latest `sliderValue` in the UI,
- the `sliderValue` variable value is restored because of `remember`,
- but the `targetValue` variable is initialized again with a new random value.

You probably want to also remember the targetValue like this:

```
var sliderValue by remember { mutableStateOf(0.5f) }
var targetValue by remember { mutableStateOf(Random.nextInt(0..100)) }
```